# Internal certificate used when installing Helm Tiller Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

The error below is triggered when executing `kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps logs install-helm`.

I've tried regenerating the certificates, and bypassing the certificate check. Somehow it is using my internal certificate instead of the certificate of the source.

```sh
root@dev # kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps logs install-helm
+ helm init --tiller-tls --tiller-tls-verify --tls-ca-cert /data/helm/helm/config/ca.pem --tiller-tls-cert /data/helm/helm/config/cert.pem --tiller-tls-key /data/helm/helm/config/key.pem
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Error: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: x509: certificate is valid for *.tdebv.nl, not kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

What might be the issue here? Screenshot below is the error Gitlab is giving me (not much information either).

[image]

Comment: How are you installing helm? from the gitlab ui? Looks like the container has a CA that doesn't trust `https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com`

Comment: That's right @Rico. Gitlab UI. I can't seem to find anything about the issue either. Not even on the Gitlab Issue tracker.

Comment: What container is it using to install helm?  what's the pod spec in k8s? or deployment spec? can you post those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After having the same issue I finally found the solution for it:

**In the `/etc/resolv.conf` file on your Master and Worker nodes you have to search and remove the `search XYZ.com` entry.**

If you are using Jelastic you have to remove this entry every time after a restart. It gets added by Jelastic automatically. I already contacted them so maybe they will fix it soon.

Comment: And how were you able to do this? I've set this up through my Gitlab UI and Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Not sure what you want to hear. I removed the line in the file with the vi command. Because I don't use GCP I cannot tell you how you can do this on GCP.

Comment: This was due to selecting a too small node on GCP. n1-standard-1 is the smallest node which is required

Comment: Thanks for me i only needed to set static IP-address on my microk8s test installation.

Answer (score 3):

Creating "~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml" with the following content solved the problem.

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
apiVersion: v1
repositories:
- caFile: ""
  cache: ~/.helm/repository/cache/stable-index.yaml
  certFile: ""
  keyFile: ""
  name: stable
  password: ""
  url: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
  username: ""
- caFile: ""
  cache: ~/.helm/repository/cache/local-index.yaml
  certFile: ""
  keyFile: ""
  name: local
  password: ""
  url: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
  username: ""
EOF

#helm init
```

Comment: This is a great solution for those of us on servers that have /etc/resolv.conf forcibly overwritten...thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on Kubernetes with the Calico network stack under Debian Buster.

Checking a lot of configs and parameters, I ended up with getting it to work by changing the policy for the forward rule to ACCEPT. This made it clear that the issue is somewhere around the firewall.

Running iptables -L gave me the following unveiling warning: # Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them

The output given by the list command does not contain any Calico rules. Running iptables-legacy -L showed me the Calico rules, so it seems obvious now why it didn't work. So Calico seems to use the legacy interface.

The issue is the change in Debian to iptables-nft in the alternatives, you can check via:

ls -l /etc/alternatives | grep iptables

Doing the following:

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

Now it works all fine! Thanks to *Long* at the Kubernetes Slack channel for pointing the route to solving it.